# The meaning v of this phrase in Satipattana Sutta

Tags: mindfulness

I want to know the proper meaning (a full breakdown) of what this phrase means in Satipanna Sutta. It's in pali.

Iti ajjhattaṃ vā kāye kāyānupassī viharati, bahiddhā vā kāye kāyānupassī viharati, ajjhattabahiddhā vā kāye kāyānupassī viharati. Samudayadhammānupassī vā kāyasmiṃ viharati, vayadhammānupassī vā kāyasmiṃ viharati, samudayavayadhammānupassī vā kāyasmiṃ viharati. ‘Atthi kāyo’ti vā panassa sati paccupaṭṭhitā hoti yāvadeva ñāṇamattāya paṭissatimattāya anissito ca viharati, na ca kiñci loke upādiyati. Evampi kho, bhikkhave, bhikkhu kāye kāyānupassī viharati.

Especially I want to know on this as well.

Atthi kāyo’ti vā panassa sati paccupaṭṭhitā hoti yāvadeva ñāṇamattāya paṭissatimattāya anissito ca viharati, na ca kiñci loke upādiyati.

Answer (score 1):

> And so they meditate observing an aspect of the body internally,
>   externally, and both internally and externally.
>
> Iti ajjhattaṃ vā kāye kāyānupassī viharati, bahiddhā vā kāye
>   kāyānupassī viharati, ajjhattabahiddhā vā kāye kāyānupassī viharati;
>
> They meditate observing the body as liable to originate, as liable to
>   vanish, and as liable to both originate and vanish.
>
> samudayadhammānupassī vā kāyasmiṃ viharati, vayadhammānupassī vā
>   kāyasmiṃ viharati, samudayavayadhammānupassī vā kāyasmiṃ viharati.
>
> Or mindfulness is established that the body exists, to the extent
>   necessary for knowledge and mindfulness. They meditate independent,
>   not grasping at anything in the world.
>
> ‘Atthi kāyo’ti vā panassa sati paccupaṭṭhitā hoti. Yāvadeva
>   ñāṇamattāya paṭissatimattāya anissito ca viharati, na ca kiñci loke
>   upādiyati.
>
> That’s how a mendicant meditates by observing an aspect of the body.
>
> Evampi kho, bhikkhave, bhikkhu kāye kāyānupassī viharati.

This is according to suttacentral.net. See: https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato
Under settings you can activate showing the Pāli.

Comment: I marked this post down because it is just a copy & paste of an inaccurate translation.

Comment: I converted the quoted portion into a quote block.

Answer (score -1):

The terms "sati paccupaṭṭhitā" mean "mindfulness of the present moment", whereas "sati" means mindfulness. This could make a huge difference given the wide range of interpretations of 'mindfulness', especially in the West.